# Trouble to get simple ReactiveUI sample to work

Tags: c#, winforms, reactiveui

I just started learning ReactUI and tried to follow this sample: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/801986/Using-ReactiveUI-for-WinForms-MVVM-Design
I start getting frustrated because I am not able to get it to work.  This is the code inquestion (copied from the sample):

```
//
// ViewModel example
//
namespace WinFormMVVM.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeViewModel : ReactiveUI.ReactiveObject
    {
        string ModelString;
        public string EnteredText
        {
            get { return ModelString; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref ModelString, value);}
        }

        string statusString = "";
        public string Status
        {
            get{return statusString;}
            set{this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref statusString,value);}
        }

        public ReactiveCommand<object> OKCmd { get; private set; }

        public HomeViewModel
        {
            var OKCmdObs = this.WhenAny(vm => vm.EnteredText, 
                s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Value));
            OKCmd = ReactiveCommand.Create(OKCmdObs);           // <--- Trouble starts here
            OKCmd.Subscribe(_=> Status = EnteredText + " is saved.");
        }
    }
}
```

I marked the line in question.
Compiling this code results in this error:

`Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IObservable<bool>' 
to 'System.Action'`

I use ReactiveUI for WinForms Version 7.4.0 (which seems to be the latest stable version)

The ReactiveUI samples on github tell me to use `ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(...)` which is an unknown method.  It is realy frustrating...

Can someone please explain how to get the sample to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the sample to work.  Just as a reference for others here the changes I had to do:

```
//
// ViewModel example
//
namespace WinFormMVVM.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeViewModel : ReactiveUI.ReactiveObject
    {
        string ModelString;
        public string EnteredText
        {
            get { return ModelString; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref ModelString, value);}
        }

        string statusString = "";
        public string Status
        {
            get{return statusString;}
            set{this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref statusString,value);}
        }

        public ReactiveCommand<object> OKCmd { get; private set; }

        public HomeViewModel
        {
            var OKCmdObs = this.WhenAny(vm => vm.EnteredText, 
                                        s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Value));

            // OKCmd = ReactiveCommand.Create(OKCmdObs);    
            // OKCmd.Subscribe(_=> Status = EnteredText + " is saved.");

            OKCmd = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() => {
                Status = EnteredText + " is saved.";
                return Observable.Return(true);
            }, OKCmdObs);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the `ReactiveCommand`factory methods accept either an `Action` or `Func<T>` as the first argument defining what to do when executing the command. The next parameter is the one you're looking for which sets `CanExecute`. To make your code work change

```
OKCmd = ReactiveCommand.Create(OKCmdObs);
```

to

```
OKCmd = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => { /* Do nothing */ }, OKCmdObs);
```

You should probably also change

```
public ReactiveCommand<object> OKCmd { get; private set; }
```

to

```
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> OKCmd { get; private set; }
```

`Unit` is a type used to indicate that there's no real value, just a signal.

It looks like the tutorial uses RxUI v6.x, which has slightly different syntax than v7.x for `ReactiveCommand`s. You can read up on `ReactiveCommand` here: https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/

Comment: Reading the text you recommend: they talk about `ReactiveComman.CreateAsyncTask(...)` all over the place.  I can not find these methods.  Are they no longer available in 7.x?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It seems it's not updated. It's now called `ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask`

Comment: Jon: Thanks for the explanation.  It gave me a good kick in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this appears to work for me:

```
public class HomeViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string ModelString;

    public string EnteredText
    {
        get { return ModelString; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref ModelString, value); }
    }

    private string statusString = string.Empty;

    public string Status
    {
        get { return statusString; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref statusString, value); }
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<System.Reactive.Unit, bool> OKCmd { get; private set; }

    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        var OkCmdObs = this.WhenAny(vm => vm.EnteredText,
            s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Value));
        OKCmd = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() =>
        {
            Status = EnteredText + " is saved.";
            return Observable.Return(true);
        }, OkCmdObs);
    }
}
```

Note, this is VS2019 with v10.1.5 of ReactiveUI